# Use a non-perl daemon as an HTTP::Daemon Object in perl

Tags: perl, http, daemon

I have an apache web server running an HTTP daemon on port 80. This web server won't let me start any other http daemons. Is there a way I can link the already-running apache http daemon as an HTTP::Daemon object in perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, although you could run it on another port and then configure Apache to proxy the request to the other server.

I'd write a PSGI or (if you want to do voodoo) mod_perl application instead.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to a port is exclusive. When the Apache httpd already occupies port 80, simply tell HTTP::Daemon to bind to a different port with the argument `LocalPort` in the constructor.

Without root privileges, you may use numbers above 1024, preferably [between 49152 and 65535](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers).

Comment: No, you misinterpreted the question. I said I can't create any other daemons. What I meant was would I be able to use the already-running apache daemon as an HTTP::Daemons object?

Comment: You said Apache httpd won't let you start any other HTTP daemons. I can believe that, and the work-around is in my answer. However, I won't believe that you cannot create any other daemons at all.